# Error No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un código en c#, donde trato de conectarme a una bandeja de correos de hotmail y me da este error:

> No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó
>   expresamente dicha conexión

Código utilizado:

```
    using EAGetMail

            MailServer oServer = new MailServer("pop3.live.com",
                        "****@hotmail.com", "*******", ServerProtocol.Pop3);

            MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");
            oServer.SSLConnection = true;
            oServer.Port = 995;

`oClient.Connect(oServer);`
```

He tratado de conectarme a varios correos y siempre me da el mismo error.

¿Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: si configuras outlook se conecta y accede a los mail con esa info que usas en el codigo ?

Comment: Si el correo y contraseña son los que uso para conectarme y puedo acceder pero hemos colocado varios correo y todos dicen lo mismo, hemos probado con hotmail y gmail

Comment: no probaron usando otra libreria?

Comment: No, necesito ingresar a un buzón de correo de office 365, leer los correos no leídos, procesarlos y luego enviarlos a otra bandeja, que otra librería puedo utilizar? todo en c# .net

Answer (score 1):

Descargé el nuget con el nombre EAGetMail
[image: imagen del nuget]

Probé ese mismo código que tienes ahí, y tuve que configurar en outlook el acceso por POP, como se explica en el sgte enlace https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040
[image: estas son las instrucciones para POP]

Y logró ejecutar la instruccion "Connect" correctamente.

De todas formas, te recomiendo el nuget MailKit 
https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit